# How to add a document to a collection in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called 'users'.  I'm trying to add a user to the collection after Google authentication but I keep getting the following error:

FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1.

Here is the code

```
this.googlePlus.login({
    'scopes': '', 
    'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId,
    'offline': true,
})
.then(user => {
    // save user data on the native storage
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<User> = this.afs.collection<User>(`users/`);
    const data: User = {
        email: user.email,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        uid: user.uid
    };
    userRef.set(data)
    .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google+ is being discontinued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B#Shutdown_of_consumer_version) so you should look at Firebase Authentication, or [GCP's new Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp).

In the case of Firebase Authentication, you must listen to the `.onAuthStateChanged` observer. Once it fires off your `user` object, you then take that and write a new user document to a users collection in Firestore.  Best practise is to use the `uid` of the `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` as the user document ID in your `users` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `userRef` refers to a collection, and the type of object is called a CollectionReference.  You're attempting to call `set()` on it with some object that should become a new document in that collection.  But that's not the way it works.  Instead, it looks like you want to call `add()` to add a new document with a new random ID.

If you somehow already know the ID of the new user document, you should build a DocumentReference with that id, then use `set()` on that DocumentReference to create the document.

Comment: Is it also correct that the op could keep the `userRef` call its `doc()` method to get a docRef (even without an id and have google generate one), then call set on that docRef?

Comment: Maybe, that would be specific to AngularFire, which I don't really know well.  I'm speaking mostly in terms of the underlying JS AP that AngularFire wraps.  The point is that set() can only be used on a document reference, not a collection reference.

Comment: And in JS...https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc

Comment: Sure, take your pick.

Comment: In otherwords, @D.Hodges, an alternative is to just change `userRef.set(data)` to `userRef.doc().set(data)` (maybe DougStevenson can weigh in on the trailing slash in your 'users/' collection.  I've never seen it used that way).

Comment: Leading and trailing slashes are ignored.